# Word 2016 multi-level numbering is always stuck on 1

Tags: microsoft-word

In Word 2016, for some reason the multi-level numbering doesn't want to work correctly. For example, I can have:

```
1
  1.1
    1.1.1
```

However the following won't work:

```
1
  1.2
    1.2.1
```

For the third level, it reverts to `1.1.1`.

In the following image, I have an example of this. Even though Word sees I'm in `6.2`, the next level is `6.1.1`.

[image: List shown]

When I go to *Set Numbering Value* > *Continue from previous list*, it shows `6.2.1` in the grey box, but the preview and result still shows `6.1.1`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What I notice is that, in the 'Enter formatting for number' field in your screen capture, the two 1s aren't shaded gray to indicate that they're generated values; but they should be. Did you just type those in, or did you use the 'Include level number from' field to add them?

Comment: That was it, thank you @cnread . I just changed it to be generated now.